# How could I get the name of a specific file but not use the extension from a path?

Tags: python, string, path

I found out a method called `os.path.basename` to get the filename with extension. But even when I import os, I am not able to call it `path.basename`. Is it possible to call it as directly as basename?

Comment: Share the code please. The full error stack would also be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by you are not able to call `path.basename`? If you use `import os` you need to be using `os.path.basename()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a little trouble understanding your problem at hand, just throwing some ideas out there

**1**

```
>>> import os 
>>> name = os.path.basename('~/python/data.txt')
>>> name
'data.txt'
```

**2**

```
>>> from os import path
>>> name = path.basename('~/python/data.txt')
>>> name
'data.txt'
```

**3**

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> name = basename('~/python/data.txt')
>>> name
'data.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it you are looking for?

```
from os.path import basename
basename('~/test.txt')
```